# How to check which offer a user is currently subscribed to in Play billing library v5.0 - Android

Tags: android, in-app-subscription, android-developer-api, play-billing-library, google-play-billing

Currently, `billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync` returns a [list of purchases](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/migrate-gpblv5#processing-purchases) which only has data like productId, purchaseToken, purchaseTime, etc.

But I have a scenario where my app has 1 monthly base plan and 2 offers underneath it- offer1 and offer2. Now the user has selected offer1 and is now subscribed. What if the user accidently uninstalls the app and reinstalls it? The user should be able to jump into the app with offer1. Is there a way to know which offer the user has currently availed? (in my case offer1)

Comment: Did you find the answer that how can we identify which offers are purchased from which base plan?

Comment: I got an anwser from the team on github issues. Link - https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/issues/538#issuecomment-1310714274 . No direct answer. I don't think it's still possible (https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/issues/586)